# How to finds any values that starts with a certain character using Azure storage table & node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I want to get a line of data where PartitionKey start with "1"
the synonym of this SQL command but instead using azure table query,
Thank you.

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE "1%" ;
```

Comment: Just like that?, the partition key could be (1_EngineOn, 1_gps_toggle,2_EngineOff,.....) but i just want the events that starts with 1, im writing this just to make sure that you fully understand my question,thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer. I created some sample entities using the data you provided and the query fetches only the entities starting with `1_`.

Comment: Thank you if you be so kind can you explain what is the difference between ge and lt i think "ge" is (greater or equal) but "lt" im not sure

Comment: `lt` is `less than` :). Please see this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an OData query like

`PartitionKey ge '1_' and PartitionKey lt '2'`